# File System Access API on Safari iOS - createSyncAccessHandle() UnknownError: 'invalid platform file handle'

Tags: javascript, ios, promise, mobile-safari, file-system-access-api

I'm currently refactoring an app to use the OPFS to save images on an iPad for a use-case where a user needs to take pictures in a location that doesn't have wi-fi but storing all of the images in RAM will cause the iPad to crash.

I've managed to create a working OPFS Worker that works on my local Windows machine on Chrome and Firefox, but I can't get it working on the test iPad. [EDIT] What it does is sends the base64 text to the worker and saves it as a text file, that I can retrieve later.

The iPad I'm using to test is iOS version 16.3.1.

The iPad I'm trying to develop for is iOS version 15.7.3.

As far as I can tell, Safari iOS has had OPFS compatibility since 15.2.

I was able to narrow down the problem to one specific error (via Web Inspector):

`Unhandled Promise Rejection: UnknownError: invalid platform file handle`

It references back to the following code (within a Web Worker):

```js
    const root = await navigator.storage.getDirectory();
    const saveHandle = await root.getFileHandle(input.fileName, { create: true });
    const access = await saveHandle.createSyncAccessHandle(); //<-- ERROR
```

`input.fileName` is usually something like `S0I0.txt`, based off a labeling system I have for organizing the images.

It doesn't seem to matter if the file is being created by `getFileHandle()` or not.

I haven't been able to extract anything else from the `Error` object.

I also have been unable to find any reference to this specific error anywhere. It's not on the list of `Exceptions` on the [web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileHandle/createSyncAccessHandle#examples). In fact, the only reference to the exact phrase I've found is on [an old ticket from 2013](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=271533).

As far as I can tell, the 2 preceding statements work correctly and generate the right objects, being `FileSystemDirectoryHandle` and `FileSystemFileHandle`, respectively.

[UPDATE]:

I did some more digging and found some references to reserved filenames (like `con` on Windows) so I tried some tests using different filenames (like `test1.txt`) and I also tried removing the `{ create: true }` clause with no success.

I'm starting to feel like this is a compatibility issue, but that doesn't sound right seeing as [multiple](https://webkit.org/blog/12257/the-file-system-access-api-with-origin-private-file-system/) [sources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) [say](https://caniuse.com/native-filesystem-api) that Safari iOS 15.2 and later can support OPFS, but not the rest of the File System Access API. Am I unwittingly using an incompatible part of the FSA API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an issue on WebKit's side that was reported in https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=251460, which is marked as fixed. It might be that your devices don't have a Safari version that includes this fix, since Safari releases are bound to the operating system. If your app is publicly accessibly, I'm happy to test on one of my devices, which all are on whatever the latest beta version may be.

Comment: Oh good, so I'm not crazy. I'm going to system update my device and give it a shot. Since this was 'fixed' in January I'm hoping that it's made it into one of the 3 versions released since then. I don't see anything in the release notes but it's probably too small to be of note. Unfortunately this is an internal app so I can't get you a link to share, but I appreciate the offer nonetheless, however this app doesn't do much aside from save and retrieve files, so if `createSyncAccessHandle()` works on any of your devices then that's all I need. Thanks!

Comment: Question: I've updated to 16.4.1 and now I can't get any console messages to show. I did some digging and it looks like it's something to do with this `isInspectable` property, but none of the implementations listed are in Javascript. How do I enable `isInspectable` if I'm not using Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know the answer to this specific question. What I can tell you is that up until very recently there was a problem with the origin private file system in subworkers (see the [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=255458)), so maybe you're running into something similar when you try to use the API from a `WKWebView`. This is pure speculation, though.

Comment: Just for closure's sake, turns out it was a version issue with the iMac I was testing with vs the new iOS version of the iPad [too old].

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Good to hear the mystery is solved.